# ImportError in terminal for importing a module created in VS Code

Tags: python, indentation, importerror

Created in VS Code a file containing a new class called Book. When I try and import it via terminal (on MacBook), I get this error message:

> ImportError: No module named Book.

This is the VS Code code:

```py
    class Book:

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
```

And the terminal:

```py
    from book import Book
```

What causes this import error, and how do I fix this?

Comment: 1. What is the filename of the class? 2. Have you checked `Python code indentation`? The `__init__` method should be indented.

Comment: Filename is book.py, the indentation is right in the source code, i copied and pasted here and it somehow lost the indentation of the __init__ line, dont know why?

Answer (score 2):

you may need to add `__init__.py` file to the folder

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat directories
> containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a
> common name, such as string, unintentionally hiding valid modules that
> occur later on the module search path.

Answer (score 1):

I have created two files in a directory in the following structure:

```
.
├── book.py
└── main.py
```

The file contents are given below:

`book.py`:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
```

`main.py`:

```
from book import Book

sample_book = Book("Uncle Tom")
print(sample_book.title)
```

Then I opened a terminal in the same directory and run the `main.py` using Python 3.

```
python3 main.py
```

Output:

```
Uncle Tom
```

Answer (score 0):

The current directory is member of the Python path. That means that if your module is in the folder that VSCode sets as the current directory for Python execution, you will find it directly from VSCode.

To find it from the command line, you have either to first change (`cd`) to that directory, or if you want to find it from anywhere, you have to append (or prepend) that folder to the Python path:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/VSCode_folder;${PYTHONPATH} python script.py
```

If a `PYTHONPATH` is already present in the environment, or

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/VSCode_folder python script.py
```

if it is not.